# How to access 127.0.0.2 3 etc to other computer/network over LAN?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, local-area-network, localhost

I have 2 computer(A n B) which connected same wifi. If i want to access my localhost(127.0.0.1) from computer A to B  i just enter LAN IP(example http://192.168.99.5) on computer B. But how to access 127.0.0.2 or 127.0.0.3 etc to other computer?

Comment: `But how to access 127.0.0.2 or 127.0.0.3 etc to other computer?` - You can't. - https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3330

Comment: I can't follow what you're asking, but you can have OpenSSH tunneling/forwarding packets so you can access https://127.0.0.2:80 and have it actually connect to 192.168.99.6:80. http://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any packets with an address in the `127.0.0.0/8` range can never appear on any network anywhere. Traffic sent to an address in that range will immediately loop back inside the host.

Start with [*RFC 1700, Assigned Numbers*](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1700.txt):

> (g)   {127, }
>
> Internal host loopback address.  Should never appear outside a host.

There are other RFCs in that vein, including the one mentioned by @joeqwerty in the comment, [*RFC 3330, Special-Use IPv4 Addresses*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3330):

> 127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host loopback address.  A datagram sent by a higher level protocol to an
> address anywhere within this block should loop back inside the host.
> This is ordinarily implemented using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback,
> but no addresses within this block should ever appear on any network
> anywhere [RFC1700, page 5].

Comment: There is a related question (_[Can my default gateway of router be 127.0.0.1?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/40153/8499)_) on [networkengineering.se].

Answer (score 1):

If you need to connect to a local loopback  `127.0.0.0/8` network on another computer, the connection must originate from the same machine. You may need to do so for example if a service is only bind to `127.0.0.1`; therefore, it cannot be connected using LAN/public IP.  This can be achieved several ways, but using an SSH tunnel is the easiest to set up.